# How to set up file system configuration to save files on another hard drive

Tags: 7, files

Since users are allowed to upload large files i have setup like this: sites/dafault/files/uploadfolder/username/folder/

Shortcut to another harddrive on server is setup so files under /sites/dafault/files/uploadfolder and all coming after are saved to that drive.

When admin or user uploads the file i see that correct folders are made (files/uploadfolder/username123/folder/) but the file itself can not be saved with this error:

Warning in log: "The upload directory public://uploadfolder/username123/folder for the file field field_name could not be created or is not accessible. A newly uploaded file could not be saved in this directory as a consequence, and the upload was canceled."
Permissions are 777.

Comment: Assuming that the server is apache, please check if you have `Options +FollowSymLinks` option in the .htaccess file under `sites/default/files` folder.

Comment: Yep its there and enabled.

Comment: Any idea what could be wrong ?

Comment: Sorry, no other idea. I'm also using a secondary drive for my files and the files folder is a symlink to a folder in another drive. I didn't have such problems. I am on a Linux machine. If you are on a windows machine, you may want to create a junction using `mklink /J <link> <target>`

Comment: I'm on Linux also. Strange thing is that it creates all subfolders as give by token but the file itself will not.

Comment: Can you check what `umask` command returns? ideally it should be `0002` or `0022`.

Comment: yep, 0002. I made all fields lead to private instead of public. Its working now.